# Error Running NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am new to NodeJS and I can't not run the old project. 
Here is error message...

> Error: Most middleware (like compress) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

And Here is code of server.js

```
/*** Module dependencies.*/
/*jshint loopfunc: true */
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    logger = require('mean-logger');

//Load configurations

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    config = require('./config/config'),
    auth = require('./config/middlewares/authorization'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);
var register_models = require('./app/register_models');
register_models();


//Bootstrap models
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models';
var walk = function(path) {
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file) {
        var newPath = path + '/' + file;
        var stat = fs.statSync(newPath);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            if (/(.*)\.(js|coffee)/.test(file)) {
                require(newPath);
            }
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            walk(newPath);
        }
    });
};
walk(models_path);

//bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);


var app = express();


//express settings
require('./config/express')(app, passport, db);

//Bootstrap routes
require('./config/routes')(app, passport, auth);

//Start the app by listening on <port>
var port = process.env.PORT || config.port;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Express app started on port ' + port);

//Initializing logger
logger.init(app, passport, mongoose);

//expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You have updated your express to version 4 which had breaking changes. Check the guide on their site on how to upgrade from 3.0 to 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of express 4.x.x, If your run npm install command and package.json in your project folder has a dependency like "express": "^4.10.6" or "express": "*", which in turn will install latest version of express. It (express 4.x.x) will not let your old app (written in express 3.x.x or < version) run.

This problem can be solved by either installing express < 4.x.x for example:

```
npm install express@3.x.x
```

or by installing each missing module that logged in node console (exactly like your above mentioned missings)

or here is nice article to follow migration from express 3.x.x to 4.x.x

[Migration Article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/expressjs-4-0-new-features-and-upgrading-from-3-0#removed-bundled-middleware)

Happy Helping!